# Combobox selection changes, selected value to be appended in textbox after a certain character

Tags: excel, vba

I have certain values in combobox and when I change the values, the value that I have selected should be populated in the textbox after a certain word.
The code I have written keeps appending the combobox selected values instead of clearing and just populating the newly selected value.
Please help.

```
Private Sub cboTrial_Change()
    Dim Searchthis As String
    Dim StartTxt, MidTxt, EndTxt As String
    Dim index As Integer

Dim s As String
StartTxt = VBA.vbNullString
MidTxt = VBA.vbNullString
EndTxt = VBA.vbNullString

Cells(1, 5).Value = cboTrial.Value

If Me. cboTrial.Enabled = VBA.vbTrue Then
    If Me. cboTrial.Value <> VBA.vbNullString Then
        Call FlagControl(cboTrial, VBA.vbFalse)
    End If
    Searchthis = "by"
    index = InStr(1, txt, Searchthis) + 2

       If index > 0 Then
            StartTxt = mid(txt, 1, index)
            MidTxt = Me. cboTrial.Value
            EndTxt = mid(txt, index, Len(txt))
            txt= StartTxt & MidTxt & EndTxt
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have written this in the combobox change event.

Comment: If you need to extend or change your question, please [edit] your question instead of writing a comment :)

Comment: What is txt? Does the value of txt gets changed after the `txtGCMS` is updated?

Comment: Sorry..that was a mistake... its txt..name of the txtbox where i have to append my original text and this combobox value after by